# AWS Api Credentials in application.conf file - Safe enough?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, credentials, typesafe

I am wondering if its safe enough to put the AWS Api Credentials (or credentials in general) in a .conf file? I dont think so and want to ask if there is any easy to use approach to encrypt and decrypt the credentials. I am using JAVA with Eclipse IDE. Does anyone have a hint for a newbie in this section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the ".conf" file? Is it a configuration file for an application? If that's the case, then no, it's not safe enough.

Amazon has a [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) describing best practices for access keys. Their recommendation for applications is to attach a role to whatever is running the application (EC2 / ECS / Lambda).

The biggest benefit of using a role is that the credentials it provides are temporary: they have a maximum lifetime of 12 hours, and a default lifetime of 1 hour. So if someone manages to extract them from your server, they won't be able to do long-term damage (unlike the "permanent" access keys associated with users).

While that helps, you still need to restrict the scope of those credentials (ie, don't use wildcards in their permission policies). And you should be monitoring your deployment for invalid credential use (ie, an API call that is made from somewhere outside of your VPC).

If you're talking about credentials for development use, [AWS already has a place to store those](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html). However, you don't need to store credentials anywhere if you use AWS Single-SignOn, which gives you limited-lifetime credentials for CLI/SDK use.

And if you're talking about credentials for a mobile application, look into Cognito and AWS Amplify.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I dont use anything else but S3 from AWS. I have a CloudFoundry App and there i use S3 as a permament storage. I saw the place which AWS is proposing. But i am wondering what is the difference regarding security between a file like '~/.aws' and a conf-file with https://github.com/lightbend/config ? Surely I will research further for the limited lifetime. Think I have to put a token or something to get new valid credentials for each time ...

Comment: Any unencrypted file stored in your home directory is equivalently (in)secure. The problem with a separate configuration file is that you would normally deploy that with the application, which is arguably more insecure, especially if you accidentally check it into source control.